# Use "Keys *" of Redis in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, request

In my Redis Client when I write : Keys *. I've all keys of my database.
But when I try to write the same thing in Ruby, like that:

```
@list_keys = REDIS.keys *
```

It doesn't take '*'.

Do you have any idea how I could replace the '*' ?

Comment: Have you tried `'*'` - with quotes?

Comment: Yes I tried with quotes and it doesn't work.

Comment: What happens then? Error? Empty result?

Comment: PSA: you should work hard to avoid using `KEYS` on a production server, as it is very expensive. `SCAN` is preferred, but "do it a different way" is even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If REDIS is an instance of your redis client, you can do

```
REDIS.keys('*')
```

Comment: You can call just `REDIS.keys`, `'*'` is a default param.

Comment: Thank you very much, both operate.